# Android transform Path to display "normally" using Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, path

I have created a Path in Android. I am not yet able to display this Path as desired. When I display the Path, it displays with the 0,0 coordinate starting in the upper left corner and positive y values display going down the screen. I would like to display the Path as if the coordinate system started in the lower left corner and the y values increased going up, as might be expected using "normal" cartesian coordinates.

I would like to know what Matrix transformations, I would need to perform on the Path to achieve this.

Logically, it seems that a 180 degree "flip" and a 90 degree rotate should acheive this. So I did some testing and have the pattern looking somewhat as it should with a -90 skew and a 90 rotation. The problem I have now, it that after the skew operation, the lines are not straight anymore. This leads me to believe that my skew transformation might be off.

Is it possible to have the lines display straight and in the desired orientation using Path and Matrix? If so, how?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initLayout();
}

private void initLayout() {
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // run the sampleCase after the View has been laid-out
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            // run sampleCase
            sampleCase(iv);

        }
    });
}

public void sampleCase(ImageView iv){
    Path path = getInitialPath();

//      drawPath(iv, path);

    drawPath(iv, reorientPath(iv, path));
}

public Path reorientPath(View view, Path path){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // skew -90
    matrix.setSkew(-90f, -90f);
    path.transform(matrix);
    matrix.reset();

    // rotate 90 CW
    matrix.setRotate(90f);
    path.transform(matrix);

    path = translatePathToView(path);
    path = scalePathToView(view, path);

    return path;
}

private Path translatePathToView(Path path){
    // moves the path into the visible field
    RectF bounds = getBounds(path);
    float xTrans = 0f - bounds.left;
    float yTrans = 0f - bounds.top;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setTranslate(xTrans, yTrans);
    path.transform(matrix);
    return path;
}


private Path scalePathToView(View view, Path path){
    RectF bounds = getBounds(path);

    float viewW = view.getWidth();
    float viewH = view.getHeight();

    float pathW = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float pathH = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

    float scaleFactor = Math.min(viewW/pathW, viewH/pathH);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    path.transform(matrix);

    return path;
}

public RectF getBounds(Path path){
    RectF bounds = new RectF();
    path.computeBounds(bounds, false);
    if (DEBUG){
        Log.d(TAG, "bounds.bottom: " + bounds.bottom);
        Log.d(TAG, "bounds.top: " + bounds.top);
        Log.d(TAG, "bounds.left: " + bounds.left);
        Log.d(TAG, "bounds.right: " + bounds.right);
    }
    return bounds;
}

public Path getInitialPath(){
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(50, 0);
    path.lineTo(90, 0);
    path.lineTo(100, 10);
    path.lineTo(100, 100);
    path.lineTo(30, 100);
    path.lineTo(0, 70);
    path.lineTo(0, 50);
    path.lineTo(50, 0);
    return path;
}

public void drawPath(ImageView iv, Path path){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Paint paint = setupPaint(2, Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

private Paint setupPaint(int width, int color) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    return paint;
}

}
```

Before transformations:

[image: Before transformations]

After transformations, close but no cigar:

[image: After transformations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more precision to the float value passed into Matrix.setSkew() gives me the desired result.

```
matrix.setSkew(-180000f, -180000f);
```

The top, bottom, left and right lines are straight now.

[image: Strait lines]